# Were the giant, floor-mounted Joysticks joysticks from a real arcade game?

Tags: controllers, arcade, satans-hollow

In the 1983 movie *Joysticks*, the characters play two arcade games (*Satan's Hollow* and *Super Pac-Man*) using giant, floor-mounted joysticks. These come up to about waist height and terminate in a red plastic ball, about the size of a large bowling ball.  The players grip the ball with both hands, pulling or pushing it forwards, backwards, left, and right to swivel the stick.  The ball also contains finger-activated fire buttons.

[image: Film still from Joysticks showing the above-mentioned joysticks]

The original cabinet versions of *Satan's Hollow* and *Super Pac-Man* that I've played both had normal-sized joysticks.  But that isn't to say that these or other games weren't also released with the film's fancier (if more unwieldy) controllers.  Were these giant controllers part of or inspired by *any* commercially released arcade game?  Or were they perhaps available as aftermarket equipment?  Or were they strictly an invention of the filmmakers?